# Prepare for topic modelling on Wikipedia data LDA

Tags: machine-learning, configuration, lda, topic-modeling

I am training my LDA model on old Wikipedia data-set(~1GB).

I downloaded using Kiwix and cleaned it.

But when I run it on my laptop with 4 cores(i5) and 8GB RAM, it is eating up all the RAM but CPU is only 25% utilized(may be because my trainer runs only on one core).

When I was training for 300 topics my laptop crashed. I know I need a cluster to do training so I want to know following :

1. What should be cluster configuration?
2. What should be no of topics if
   I want to train on 12GB Wikipedia data for 1000+ topics.

   Any links, reference, hints may be helpful. Thanks!